# AuthProvider with Microsoft Graph Api "Ctor not found"

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to use Microsoft.Graph Api to get a list of users. I am able to authenticate on the api. I receive the Token and basic profile info upon login.

Then I am trying to use the Microsoft.Graph.Auth SDK/nuget found [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth) to generate my requests. Here is a barebone example of what I am trying to do (you can also find this example in the doc of the package.

```
public void test()
{
    var clientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(ClientId)
        .WithTenantId(TenantId)
        .Build();

    var authProvider = new IntegratedWindowsAuthenticationProvider(clientApplication);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

    var users = await graphClient.Users
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();
}
```

But I get the error `` System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Graph.Auth.IntegratedWindowsAuthenticationProvider..ctor(Microsoft.Identity.Client.IPublicClientApplication, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>)'.' `` **before** even entering the method `test()`. The message says it cannot find `IntegratedWindowsAuthenticationProvider` but the package is installed and I can navigate to the constructor (F12) without issue.

[image]

If I remove the line with `IntegratedWindowsAuthenticationProvider`, the code executes without crashing. And I can authenticate into the Api successfully. I tried moving the line after the successful authentication but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Microsoft.Graph.Auth](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth) only supports .Net 4.5 and I use 4.8. I cannot downgrade to 4.5 because of other requirements in the codebase. I tried to modify the open source project but I ran into other issues so I decided to not use this package. I implemented a basic solution containing a few methods to manage the token myself.

Here is the class that handles the cached token

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace Overwatch.AutoCAD.Authentication
{
    static class TokenCacheHelper
    {
        static TokenCacheHelper()
        {
            CacheFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".msalcache.bin3";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Path to the token cache
        /// </summary>
        public static string CacheFilePath { get; private set; }

        private static readonly object FileLock = new object();

        public static void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            lock (FileLock)
            {
                args.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV3(File.Exists(CacheFilePath)
                        ? ProtectedData.Unprotect(File.ReadAllBytes(CacheFilePath),
                                                 null,
                                                 DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
                        : null);
            }
        }

        public static void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // if the access operation resulted in a cache update
            if (args.HasStateChanged)
            {
                lock (FileLock)
                {
                    // reflect changesgs in the persistent store
                    File.WriteAllBytes(CacheFilePath,
                                       ProtectedData.Protect(args.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3(),
                                                             null,
                                                             DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
                                      );
                }
            }
        }

        internal static void EnableSerialization(ITokenCache tokenCache)
        {
            tokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
            tokenCache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my modified initial test method

```
public async void test()
{
    AuthenticationResult authResult = await PublicClientApp
        .AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, (await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync()).FirstOrDefault())
        .ExecuteAsync();
    HttpClient client = ApiHelper.CreateHttpClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/");
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
    {
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
    }));

    var users = await graphClient.Users
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();
}
```

All you have to do is link the TokenCache helper in the creation of the client app builder

```
public static void CreateApplication()
{
    var builder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
        .WithAuthority($"{Instance}{Tenant}")
    .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient");

    _clientApp = builder.Build();

    TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(_clientApp.UserTokenCache);
}
```

Of course, add try catches and fail safes based on your requirements.